# How to create Dynamic Pagination

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have done server side pagination in MVC but i am unable to show numbers and Next and prev link button dynamically.Please provide me with some idea.

```html
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">
                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.PageCount; i++) // PageCount is Number of total Pages
                {

                    <li class="page-item">
                        @if (i != Model.CurrentPageIndex) //Current Page say 1..2...3..etc
                        {

                            <a class="page-link" href="javascript:;" onclick="myClick(@i)">@i</a>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span>@i</span>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

My problem is if i have a total of 10 pages (say).I want to show Link buttons for number 1 to 5 the Next button .So that pagination navigation becomes dynamic .please help

Comment: creating a paging system is a bit complex more than it seems! [this article](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/38-How_to_build_an_efficient_pagination_system) is for .net core but it could help you understand the fundementals of pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your concern is that you want to *restrict* the number of links generated so that instead of links to every page, starting from 1 and ending at `PageCount`, the user sees only a **range** of the full list of links.

The idea here is to introduce yet another parameter, call it `numbersToShow`, that represents the total number of links you want to render.

For example, when there are 10 pages, the total number of links could be like 5.

An example function to compute the starting and ending index of this subset could be like this one:

```
static (int min, int max) GetPagingRange( int currentPage, int totalPages, int numbersToShow = 5 )
{
    if ( currentPage < 1 || totalPages < 1 || currentPage > totalPages ) throw new ArgumentException();
    if ( numbersToShow < 1 ) throw new ArgumentException();

    var min = Math.Max(1, currentPage - numbersToShow/2);
    var max = Math.Min(totalPages, currentPage + numbersToShow/2 + Math.Max( 0, min - currentPage + numbersToShow/2 ) );

    return (min, max);
}
```

What happens here is that we start at the current page and try making it the middle of the dynamic range (so we take `numbersToShow/2` to the left and to the right). Both `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` make sure we stay in the valid range.

There's also another component when computing `max` that tries to compensate the lack of the left portion of the range when you render first few pages.

Consider this example usage that shows what range values are returned:

```
    Console.WriteLine( "Total pages:    10" );
    Console.WriteLine( "Numers to show: 5" );

    int totalPages = 10;

    for ( int currentPage = 1; currentPage <= totalPages; currentPage++ )                 
    {
        var result = GetPagingRange( currentPage, totalPages );
        Console.WriteLine( $"CurrentPage: {currentPage}, starting page index: {result.min} ending page index: {result.max}");
    }
```

The output here is

```
Total pages:    10
Numers to show: 5
CurrentPage: 1, starting page index: 1 ending page index: 5
CurrentPage: 2, starting page index: 1 ending page index: 5
CurrentPage: 3, starting page index: 1 ending page index: 5
CurrentPage: 4, starting page index: 2 ending page index: 6
CurrentPage: 5, starting page index: 3 ending page index: 7
CurrentPage: 6, starting page index: 4 ending page index: 8
CurrentPage: 7, starting page index: 5 ending page index: 9
CurrentPage: 8, starting page index: 6 ending page index: 10
CurrentPage: 9, starting page index: 7 ending page index: 10
CurrentPage: 10, starting page index: 8 ending page index: 10
```

Note that although the compensation works for starting pages (e.g. when the current page is 1, the range is 1 to 5), there's no compensation when few last pages are rendered (e.g. on the last 10th page the range is 8 to 10). This could possibly be improved or you can leave it as is.

The code is also available in the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1nXYt).

Comment: Thanks ,you saved me@Wiktor Zychla